# C# Drag and Drop Image from Treeview

Tags: c#, drag-and-drop, treeview

I'm building an application for users to create game terrain using hex tiles. I have a tree view with the various tile types and have successfully managed to load the images that I want to use (png's) into the tree as the node images.

I have used the code from here http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14948/Hexagonal-grid-for-games-and-other-projects-Part as a basis for my project, although I have expanded it to allow for corner, and both "types" of half hexes.

What I want to accomplish is to drag a tile type from the Tile Catalogue tree view onto the hex grid drawn, and for that image to snap to the grid and align itself correctly. I imagine that the actual image to be drawn on the grid will end up being loaded separately as the treeview images are obviously very small versions of the original images.

Now I know there's a whole heap of items in there that I don't know how to do as yet but the first in the list is the drag and drop. All the searching I've done has turned up drag and drop examples for dragging within the treeview, or from one control to another and I'm not sure that those examples are relevant.

Can someone point me in the right direction to begin playing with this myself or give an example I could base what I need to do on?

Comment: This is clearly too broad, but here a few hints anyway: In the receiver's DragDrop event you can use the e.X & e.Y values to locate the point you have dropped the tile onto. The drag from treeview examples should help, just make sure that you can get at the real images from the dragged data. - However it may be worth considering to __not use drag& drop at all__ and instead code the mousedown/move/up event and move e.g. a panel holding a real size version of the image in the clicked node. this has the advantage that you can actually see what you are dragging..!

Comment: @TaW Thanks. Having thought about this some more, I'm going to have to have a picturebox per hex as well, so perhaps the mousedown event on the tree creates that, and then moves that to where we want.